# After installing java in linux , where the java will store what home path should i give?

Tags: centos, jdk

After installing java in linux , where the java will store what home path should i give ?

Comment: I believe you can set that stuff with JAVA_HOME environment variable and whatnot.

Comment: home-path (btw. I think this is `cwd` by default) or path for temporary files?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you `export` the Java path in either your `.bashrc` or any scripts calling java binaries.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/lib/jdk1.6.0_45
```

Make sure you use the correct path and jdk folder name. You point the `JAVA_HOME` to the parent folder that contains the `bin` and `lib` directories.

Example:

```
[User jdk1.6.0_45]$ ls -lh
total 19M
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4.0K Jul  9  2014 bin
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.3K Mar 26  2013 COPYRIGHT
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4.0K Jul  9  2014 include
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root 4.0K Jul  9  2014 jre
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4.0K Jul  9  2014 lib
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   40 Mar 26  2013 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4.0K Jul  9  2014 man
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  115 Mar 26  2013 README.html
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  19M Mar 26  2013 src.zip
```